Improving THD accuracy with unsychronized FFT
I am trying to use FFT to measure THD on a sinusoidal signal. My FFT window contains approximately four cycles, but my sample rate is not synchronized to the excitation frequency and it can drift slightly, maybe +/- 5% at the extreme.
I've improved accuracy significantly with windowing - a Dolph-Chebyshev window at 170dB attenuation has produced the biggest improvement so far - but the error is still bigger than I'd like.
Is there anything I can do to further improve accuracy? Like is there some way to improve the accuracy of the fundamental and harmonic amplitudes by incorporating the side-lobes? Or am I up against a theoretical limit? Even just some keywords I could search for would be helpful.
Edit: One thing that might help me is that I know the actual frequency of the excitation signal is, so if I can figure out the relationship between the frequency offset and the spectral leakage, I can potentially do some compensation based on the frequency offset.

Another option is to track the fundamental with a PLL and subtract out the local oscillator. You can adjust the speed of the PLL to match your expected frequency drift speed.

Years ago I wrote some code that would do a high-accuracy frequency estimation by either time-domain fit (A, w, feta), or alternatively in the frequency domain using the peak-bin interpolation technique, followed by a sample-rate conversion of the data buffer to put the true peak frequency exactly in an fft bin.  Then you can just use an un-windowed fft.
Bob
